# How to down scale image in keras for an image pyramid?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras

I'd like to use an image pyramid for deep learning as in [Deep Multi-scale for Deblurring](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.02177.pdf). How can I down scale images on the fly when using keras?

Comment: What's wrong with [`AvgPooling2D`](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#averagepooling2d) or [`MaxPooling2D`](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#maxpooling2d)?

Comment: I don't know whats wrong with them. But they seem to be the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an Average Pooling layer if the downscale rate is an integer.

```
o = AveragePooling2D(pooling_size=(2, 2))(i)
```

This will average a 2x2 window into a single pixel, which is a fairly accurate way of resizing an image by a factor of 2.

Answer (score -1):

You can find Gaussian pyramids using OpenCV.
`cv2.pyrUp()` and `cv2.pyrDown()` functions can be used to upsample and downsample the image respectively.
For more reference see: [this link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/dff/tutorial_py_pyramids.html)