# Implementing an image-pyramid with Keras

Tags: python, opencv, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

To get a scale invariance (or to detect objects at any scale) on my CNN model, I want to implement [Image Pyramids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing)). As the article explains, while creating image-pyramids, image is subjected to repeated smoothing and subsampling.

I am implementing a CNN in Keras. Is there a way with Keras to implement image pyramids? I read [one of the SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420092/how-to-down-scale-image-in-keras-for-an-image-pyramid) that says to use [AveragePooling2D](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#averagepooling2d) to achieve the pyramid effect.

Is that even correct? How could `AveragePooling2D` layer give the pyramid effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One CNN architecture that achieves you goal is the U-Net, originally introduced by [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597) paper.

It uses a sequence of convolutional and pooling layers to create a pyramid. Note that it's not an image pyramid of the input image, but the idea is to learn what is useful at different scales, not directly feed the pyramid.

Now, think about how the `AveragePooling2D` works. You select a patch of the original image, replace it with the average and then move to the next patch. This is exactly what you describe in generating an image pyramid: smoothing is achieved by the averaging, and replacing the patch with one pixel is a downsampling.

Comment: Okay. So `AveragePooling2D` would smooth and downsample the image. Does `MaxPooling2D` also give a pyramid effect?

Comment: It does, but it only downsamples by picking the largest pixel in each patch, it doesn't smooth it.

Comment: I was reading about [Alexnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlexNet). It does not use `AveragePooling2D` layer. But it does use the `MaxPooling2D` layer. As I understand, pyramid formation helps to get a scale invariance. What is the intuition of not using `AveragePooling2D` and using `MaxPooling2D`.  Would you have some idea?

Comment: Both of them lead to the formation of a pyramid and the scale invariance. There are some subtle differences, which I think are very well shown here: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Toy-example-illustrating-the-drawbacks-of-max-pooling-and-average-pooling_fig2_300020038. Max pooling keeps in a way the most relevant features, while average pooling can diminish their importance. In the end, it's also a matter of experimentation with what works best.